# How to write a thread-safe program for an n-ary tree to be consistent in python

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I had an interview question last time about lockable trees in which a node of a tree can be locked if its ancestors are not locked and also its children are not locked.

The problem I have now is that I have to make this program thread-safe.

I used so many concepts but the interviewer gave me a hint that I can solve this problem using some extra variables.

My code is given below. I couldn't find any relevant articles related to this problem on the internet. I hope you have something to help me.

My code is given below.

```py
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()
class Lockable(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.locked = False
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lockedDescendents = 0
    def mutate_lock(self,delim):
        with lock:
            self.locked = delim
    def mutate_locked_descendents(self,delim,ancestor):
        with lock:
            ancestor.lockedDescendents+=delim
    def lock(self):
        if(self.locked):
            return True
        if(self.lockedDescendents >0):
            return False

        ancestor = self.parent
        while(ancestor):
            with lock:
                if(ancestor.locked):
                    return False
            ancestor = ancestor.parent

        while(ancestor):
            self.mutate_locked_descendents(1,ancestor)
            ancestor = ancestor.parent

        self.mutate_lock(True)
            
        return True
    def unlock(self):
        if(not self.locked):
            return  False

        ancestor = self.parent
        while(ancestor):
            self.mutate_locked_descendents(-1,ancestor)
            ancestor = ancestor.parent
        self.mutate_lock(False)
        return True


c = Lockable(None)
a = Lockable(c)
b = Lockable(c)
d = Lockable(a)
e = Lockable(b)
print(a.lock())
print(b.lock())
print(a.unlock())
print(e.lock())
print(d.lock())
```

The tree needs to be consistent and if two threads collide we can kill both the threads or kill one of the threads.

- both threads can fail together but both of them must not concurrently pass together at any cost.

Comment: Are you sure that the code works? Why are you inheriting `threading.Thread` and don't start anything? -- by the way, the documentation prohibit subclassing `threading.Thread` and overriding any method other than `__init__` and `run`.

Comment: The interviewer accepted some parts and wanted me to modify the code a little bit. That made me convinced that the code maybe right. He also told that using mutex, semaphores etc are not allowed. Also this problem is possible to be solved using some extra variables. Any tips how to use extra variables to keep this tree consistent with threads.